# I am getting null stored in the date column of database this is my query

Tags: php, mysql

```
$query1="insert into checkup_form 
            set checkup_date=STR_TO_DATE('" . $medical_date. "','%d-%m-%Y'),    
            emp_id='" .$id. "' ";
```

Comment: No WHERE clause?

Comment: Show us what is in `$medical_date`

Comment: Your script is open to [SQL Injection Attack](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174). 
Even [if you are escaping inputs, its not safe!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187)
You should always use [prepared parameterized statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) 
in either the `MYSQLI_` or `PDO` API's instead of concatenating user provided values into the query. Never trust ANY user input!

Comment: $medical_date is actually taking date from excel

Comment: Well that in my experience can be quite prone to issues. Please show us some examples output in the PHP code after you have read the date from the excel sheet

Comment: insert into checkup_form set checkup_date = STR_TO_DATE('2002/01/12','%d-%m-%Y'), emp_id='45' 


Above is the error_log statement, as you can see it is taking date as 2002/01/12 from excel, but storing null in databse.

Comment: It would have been REALLY REALLY Useful to have seen that in the Question! And in future, please always put error message into the question and ALL the error message, not a summary

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this is your error statement:

> .. insert into checkup_form set checkup_date = STR_TO_DATE('2002/01/12','%d-%m-%Y'), emp_id='45'

Then the error is obvious, you have provided the WRONG FORMAT for the date you are supplying. Remember the format is supposed to tell the function what format the date you are giving it will be in, *NOT the format you want out*!

So change the format to match the input

```
STR_TO_DATE('2002/01/12','%Y/%m/%d')
```